# passing parameters from js to .aspx page using windows location

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, internet-explorer-8, window.location

I can pass parameters from javascript function to an aspx file. I use windows.location.href for that. 
When the execution gets to the aspx page, it runs and it tries to call multiple WCF services using those parameters. But the moment it calls the first one, the IE window on the back takes me to the root view that lists all available aspx pages. 
i've tried setting a breakpoint on the page load that is receiving those parametrs. I try to step through the codes, it will let me do that just fine but when it calls the first WCF service, it will do the above to the IE window BUT it will still let me continue steppng through the code after that. 
IE window should be waiting for me until I am done executing code on the server, right?

It has something to do with the combination of WCF calls & JS window.location.href statemetn. I know that for sure. It consistently is doing that at a specific line of code (the first WCF call).

I don't see this behavior if for instance, I try to pass the parameters in a session variable coming from another .aspx page.

Has anyone seen this behavior? do you know what is going on?

Thanks

--- REPHRASED---
thank you for the feedback.
hari, I am doing this from my local machine running VS 2008. I do use forms authentication.
Maybe you didn't get my questions, because I didn't phrase it properly like Diodeus thinks, so let me try again:
I collect input values form one page using JS. Then I need to pass these parameters to an aspx page using windows.location.href. 
I set up a breaking point at the page load event to make sure that execution is reachign the aspx page. and it does. 
This page successfully receives those variables and does more processing like calling external WCF services. At this point the IE window is locked and becomes unviewable because the execution is still taking place. This is normal (is this part that throw you off?).
The moment I start executing a call to the WCF service, the IE window finishes loading and it takes me to the direct browsing WHILE I am still debugging inside visual studio (like a line of code beomes highlighted in yellow). I can continue stepping throw using F10 or F11, but my IE window on the back is done!? It should continue waiting for me until all lines of codes finish processing. 
I hope this helps. Pls let me know if it does and be able to help me figure it out.

Comment: Ummmm.....? I think you need to rephrase this a bit.

Comment: I just rephrased it like you suggested.

Comment: I think we need to see some code, especially around the call to the first WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Disable directory browsing for that website (at IIS), and set a default page for the website (also at IIS).

Comment: Pls check my REPHRASED sectin.

Comment: every client has a timeout; it's not gonna wait forever. Paste the javascript code that does the redirection and code that gets executed after.

Comment: Here is the js code that I use to call my aspx page: window.location.href = "myForm.aspx?username=" + username + "&age=" + age; 

and on my aspx page, I save those values in local variables: username = Request.QueryString["username"]; age = Request.QueryString["age"]; and when I access the third line in this block: GetDetailsRequest detailsRequest = new GetDetailsRequest(); detailsRequest.UserName = username; GetDetailsResponse detailsResponse = wcfClient.GetUserDetails(detailsRequest); the IE window on the back reloads and takes me to the root view but I still can continue stepping throw